# What reasoning is behind the names of the trigonometric functions "sine", "secant" and "tangent"?

Tags: etymology, mathematics

The meanings of these words are very similar: the *[sine](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sine)* of an angle in a right triangle is the ratio of the opposite side to the hypotenuse; the *[secant](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/secant)* is the ratio of the hypotenuse to the adjacent side, and the *[tangent](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/tangent)* is the ratio of the opposite side to the adjacent side.

Since they have such similar functions, I wondered why *sine* comes from the Arabic word for *pocket*, *secant* comes from the Latin word for *cut*, and *tangent* comes from the Latin for *to touch*.  What do the etymologies have to do with the current meaning?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It's easiest to think of the trig functions on a circle- this is how they were constructed before calculators

[image]

- *sine* - is from the Latin for *bay* and/or the Arabic for *bowstring*. Picture the chord (segment from A-B) and the circle A-D-B as a bow. If you measure the length  of A-C and divide by the radius of the circle (O-A) you get the sine of the angle *theta*
- *cosine* is from "complement sin". It's the complement to the angle, so if you measure the distance from the centre to the chord (O-C) and divide by the radius you get the cos of the angle.
- *tangent* is from the Latin for *touch*. A tangent is a line that touches the circle once. By definition this meets a line to the centre at right angle, so you always have a right angle triangle and so an easy definition of the tan of the angle
- *secant* is from *cut* (Latin again). It cuts the tangent from O-E
- *cosecant, cotangent* etc are like cosine, the complements to their respective functions, but unless you do a lot of maths you probably won't meet them

Comment: +1 Very nice answer, although co- could be explained better. The *cosine* is the *sine* of the *complement* of the angle. If a is an angle, (90-a) is its complement, and cos(a)=sin(90-a), so the sine of the complement of an angle is the cosine. Same for cotangent and cosecant.

Comment: Note the spelling of *centre*.For completion, to get the secant and the tangent you also need to divide by the radius.

Comment: Could you combine your other answer with this one?  It is rather unintuitive that "bowstring" would become "bay" without knowing that it's just a misinterpretation.

Comment: @Ryan - it's more of a linguistic aside, the explanation of how the mistranslation came about. And if I merge them it loses the thread of other people's comments

Comment: All the etymologies for sine that I ran across said the spelling comes down from the Latin "sinus" including the meaning "curved surface" and this was a mistranslation of the Arabic. This might be more useful than "bay"...

Comment: Most of this answer is helpful, but I don't understand this explanation for *secant* at all. If anything, I could see how it's a sort of measure of a secant line, which cuts the circle (not the tangent).

Answer (score 3):

Chamber's 20th Century Dictionary (and a 1980-ish version of it, at that) says:

- *sine* - (*math*.) *n*. orig. the perpendicular from one end of an arc to the diameter through the other:  now (as a function of an angle) the ratio of the side opposite (or its supplement) in a right triangle to the hypotenuse ... [L. *sinus*, a bay]
- *secant* - *adj*. cutting ... [L. *secans*, *-antis*, pr.p. of *secare*, to cut.]
- *tangent* - *adj*. touching without intersecting. ... [L. *tangens*, *-entis*, pr.p. of *tangere*, to touch.]

So, basically, the words are derived from Latin (that's the 'L.').  The original definition of *sine* more closely resembles a 'bay' than the current trigonometric definition does.

Comment: This does not address the words as trig functions.

Comment: E.g. Why does "secant" *in the trig sense* come from "cutting"?  Why does "tangent" *in the trig sense* come from "touching"?  (*Sine* makes sense to me now, thanks to Martin Beckett's comment.)

Comment: This is explained somewhat better [on this site](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/53935.html)

Answer (score 2):

> Sine: from L. sinus "fold in a garment, bend, curve." Used mid-12c. by Gherardo of Cremona > in M.L. translation of Arabic geometrical text to render Arabic jiba "chord of
>   an arc, sine" (from Skt. jya "bowstring"), which he confused with jaib
>   "bundle, bosom, fold in a garment."
>   (http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=sine)

ps. Please leave this as a separate answer to preserve the comment thread below

Comment: This shows why the chord-of-an-arc *sine* is called a *sine*, but not the trigonometric function *sine*.

Comment: The length of a chord is how you calculate a sin http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chord_(geometry)

Comment: Could you expound in your answer?  That's not an obvious/ubiquitous fact.

Comment: Take a circle, draw two lines form the centre to the circumference and join them with a chord. Half of the length of the chord divided by the radius is the sin of half of the angle between the two lines. Half angles are used because there are a bunch of useful formulae for half angles. Remember sine is defined as the opposite/hypotenuse for a right angle triangle

Comment: Put it in your answer!

Comment: Then it will get migrated to maths!

Comment: And all this time I assumed that the name 'sine' came from the wave-like shape of the curve when plotted...

Comment: @Karl - you mean like a sine wave?